# VS Code Flutter installed apk in existing apk with higher version got error app not installed

Tags: flutter, apk

I have an issue with updating apk in a device where there is existing apk with lower version. I used ota_update package which the update apk download is successful but when installing the apk, it got notification "App is not installed".
Here is some of my step when building apk.

1. First build flutter apk in vs code using command : flutter build apk --release (example: v 1.0.0) in my computer.
2. Install the apk 1.0.0 into my device. The apps runs smoothly.
3. Create an apk update with v 1.0.1 in different computer (my team mate), using the same command : flutter build apk --release.
4. Update the apps using ota_update function
5. Download successfully, but when auto install run it got notification "**app not installed**".

Then I do another experiment :

1. I build update apk v1.0.1 in my own computer where the v1.0.0 built, using the command: flutter build apk --release
2. Update the apps using ota_update function
3. Download successfully, it auto installs  perfectly. The apps now has v.1.0.1.

I don't use google play store for the information

So My question is why when building an update apk with higher version in different computer then the first one **cannot be installed **in the existing apps? But when building update apk with higher version in the same computer with the first one can be installed in existing apps.

I and my team mate have the same code, version of code.

Regards,

Edwin